# building android platform partially

Tags: android, build, skia

I want to modify the Skia graphics library in Android slightly.

Is it possible to only rebuild the modified library without downloading and building the whole platform? The platform is massive and this is too much a bother..

Downloading and building the small number of projects Skia depends on seems ok to me, but the build script requires everything!

Thank you,
Tareq

Answer (score 1):

yes and no. i think manually downloading the bits you need would be more work (though less bandwidth) than just downloading everything.

as for building, you could probably get away with building just skia and pushing the individual .so files. assuming there are no other files it requires.

```
lithium:~$ ~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/adb shell ls /system/lib | sort | grep skia
libskiagl.so
libskia.so
lithium:~$
```

this also assumes nothing's statically linking it (i haven't checked) and that you don't need to change anything in header files that would mean callers need to be rebuilt.

but if you're only changing skia, you'll only have to rebuild the world once anyway. after that, you can just rebuild the bit you've changed (with something like "mmm external/skia").

don't forget to use -j when building to take advantage of all your processors/cores!

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i already tried building Skia manually, but had to download several dependencies for static libraries, and used those on my device fro dynamic linking. still the main library was built 5 times the normal size, and didn't work :(

Comment: i meant the skia in the android git repo, not the code.google.com skia (which is what i now think you're talking about).